# XmlSerializer inserting 2 xml declarations

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm writing some code to serialize some voxel model data. The serializer code works great, except for the fact that it's inserting 3 xml declarations, which causes an error when trying to de-serialize.

My code:

```
static Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

public void Save(string path) {
    /* trick to remove unessessarynamespace attributes */
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(VoxelData));

    var stream = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding);

    serializer.Serialize(stream, this, ns); // this refers to the VoxelData class

    /* converts a dictionary to an array of a temporary serializable type */
    if (voxels != null) {
        System.Type[] otherTypes = { typeof(Vector3Serializer) };
        var attrSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(voxelsave[]), null, otherTypes, new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName="voxels" }, ""); // new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "attributes" }, );

        voxelsave[] voxelSave = voxels.Select(kv => new voxelsave() { data = kv.Value, position = new Vector3Serializer(kv.Key) }).ToArray();

        attrSerializer.Serialize(stream, voxelSave, ns);
    }
    /* converts a dictionary to an array of a temporary serializable type */
    if (attributes != null) { 
        System.Type[] otherTypes = { typeof(Vector3Serializer) };
        var attrSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(attributesave[]), null, otherTypes, new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "attributes" }, ""); // new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "attributes" }, );

        attributesave[] attributeSave = attributes.Select(kv => new attributesave() { key = kv.Key, value = kv.Value }).ToArray();

        attrSerializer.Serialize(stream, attributeSave, ns);
    }
    stream.Close();
}
```

As well as some snippets of the serialization classes:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "attribute")]
public class attributesave {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public object key;

    public object value;
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "voxel")]
public class voxelsave {

    public Vector3Serializer position;

    public Voxel data;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class VoxelData {

    [XmlIgnore]
    private Dictionary<Vector3, Voxel> voxels = new Dictionary<Vector3, Voxel>();

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<object, object> attributes = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    [XmlAttribute("scale")]
    public float scale = 1.0f;

 ...

}
```

And here is an example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoxelData scale="1" />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<voxels>
  <voxel>
    <position x="0" y="0" z="0" />
    <data color="RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000)" scale="1" />
  </voxel>
</voxels><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<attributes>
  <attribute key="handle">
    <value d3p1:type="vector3" x="0" y="0" z="0" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </attribute>
</attributes>
```

As you can see there are 3 `xml?` tags, 2 of which shouldn't be there. They throw an error when trying to deserialize, if I removed the 2nd tag they deserialize fine.

My question is: why is this second tag being inserted, and how do I stop it?

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
I'd like to help but I need at least the minimum amount of code required to reproduce your error. Otherwise, you'll have to hope someone who's seen this exact problem before can just eyeball it and tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows The full code is a pretty huge file, that also relies on server other classes, so it would be quite a mess to post. Anyways the only relevant part of the code to the question is really the serialization function

Comment: Usually this is due to declaring the element/class XmlArray instead of XmlElement.  The XmlArray creates an extra level of tags.

Comment: I added some snippets of some of the classes used for serialization to the question. @jdweng hmm... as far as I can find I'm not doing that anywhere

Comment: `XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings(); settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;`? Not sure, but I think if you put that for the last 2 serializers, it should do the trick.

Comment: @JohnBustos That did it! Thanks! If you make an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: REALLY glad it helped! - I posted the solution now.

Comment: Note that in addition to three XML declarations, you also have three root elements; well-formed XML must have at most one XML declaration (and it must be at the top, if anywhere) and exactly one root element.

Comment: I think you're missing the root of the problem which is you're serializing each "object" individually and concatenating the XML.  The idiomatic way to o that is to serialize the "root" object and letting the XML Serializer serialize all of the child objects.  That may mean creating a different structure than what you have now but that would be the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: @DStanley I've realized that now and corrected it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the challenge you're facing can be fixed by adding in the extra [XmlWriterSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) to your 2 additional XML Serializers.

An example of how that would look would be:

```
var attrSerializer = new XmlSerializer(
          typeof(voxelsave[])
          , new XmlWriterSettings {OmitXmlDeclaration = true}
          , ....)
```

Glad it helped!!